# How to call a sub in first form from a second form and inserting controls into the first form

Tags: vb.net

I believe this is just a syntax issue and shouldn't be difficult, I'm just not overly familiar with VB.net.  I am using FormA to control FormB.  When I execute the command from FormA, I want to create 1+x different controls (webbrowser) on FormB.  To do this, I'm calling a subProcedure that resides in FormB and dynamically creating my controls from there.  Problem is, no controls are created or displayed.

I know the sub is called as I can step through it, but I suspect it's trying to display the controls in FormA.  If I move the sub to FormA, the controls display as expected on FormA.  Hence why I think it's a syntax issue.  So, going from the code example, how would I make sure the controls are added to FormB?

```
public sub displayonformb(byval sheetcount as integer)
for i as integer = 1 to sheetcount
    dim wb as new webbrowser
    with wb
        .name = "myname"
        .navigation(new uri("blah blah blah")
        .location = new point(((i-1)*(screenwidth / sheetcount)), hgt)
        .size = new size(wdth, hgt)
        me.controls.add(wb)
    end with
next
```

So, my assumption here is either with the .location or (much more likely) the me.controls.add(wb) statement.  I tried changing the "me." to "FormB." but studio complained that I should use 'me.' instead.

Comment: Are you calling `displayonformb` using a reference to the open `FormB` or are creating a new one? `new FormB().displayonformb(1)` Can you show us how you are calling  `displayonformb` ?

Comment: `dim wb as new webbrowser`. This is not real code. Post the code you're using, don't write parts of it here. What was asked in the previous comment is important. Post that too. The actual code.

Comment: Show how you call the method.

Comment: To answer the questions to my post:  I call the method like so:             Dim frm As New FormB
            frm.DisplayOnMainFormB(sheetCount)....  I have since adopted preciousbetine solution below to include FormB as an argument to the method.  And what's wrong with my "dim wb as new webbrowser"?  That's real code.  I may not have copied and pasted, but it's real code.  It works.

Comment: @gCanuck I guess what Jimi was trying to say was that in VS, the code isn't displayed that way. It is actually displayed as `Dim wb As New WebBrowser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Me.controls.add` when adding the items. You should pass the form as a parameter. *This is not a syntax error at all.* Try passing the form to add controls to as a parameter to the function.

```
Public Sub displayonformb(ByVal sheetcount as integer, form As Form)
    For i As integer = 1 To sheetcount
        Dim wb as new WebBrowser
        With wb
            .name = "myname"
            .navigation(new uri("blah blah blah")
            .location = new point(((i-1)*(screenwidth / sheetcount)), hgt)
            .size = new size(wdth, hgt)
            form.controls.add(wb)
        end with
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `Sub displayonformb` resides on the very form where the control has to be added, `Me.Controls.Add` is okay.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I don't think you get the question. Let me try to explain. FormB has a method(sub). FormA calls the method in FormB. This method in FormB is meant to add controls to FormA. So calling the code in my answer from FormA like this: `FormB.displayonformb(10, Me)` should work.

Comment: Since `FormB` is a type, not a form instance or object, this does not work. The `Sub` is in FormB and the control must be created on `FormB`. The `Sub` is called from `FormA`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are calling the sub on a wrong form instance. Somewhere you are writing

```
Dim frmB As New FormB()
frmB.Show()
```

Somewhere else you are writing

```
Dim frmB As New FormB() 'Creates a new form object.
frmB.DisplayOnFormB(1)
```

But this is another instance of `FormB` that is not displayed anywhere.

Instead, store a reference to the original form in a field. In `FormA` write

```
Public Class FormA
    Private m_frmB As FormB
    ...
```

Then still in `FormA` open the other form with

```
m_frmB = New FormB()
m_frmB.Show()
```

And when you want to add the control:

```
m_frmB.DisplayOnFormB(1)
```

I.e., work with the same form instance (form object).

Answer (score 1):

From the comment:

> I call the method like so:
>
> ```
>  Dim frm As New FormB frm.DisplayOnMainFormB(sheetCount)....
> ```

The problem is the `New` keyword. This means you're using a brand new **different instance of FormB**. You need a reference to the *same existing instance* already shown on the screen.